# Migrating a build definition from TFS to VSTS

Tags: tfs, build, workflow, reporting

I've been tasked with migrating a build from TFS to VSTS, I've used TFS from a developer point of view, however I've never created builds. Can anyone give me any advice where to start, good websites, tutorials, tools that might help, anything that might catch me out etc, basically my knowledge on this is very limited so anything would help. I've no doubt there must be somebody out there who can say we've done this, here is what we did...the new VSTS build will need to be a copy of the TFS build however some analysis needs to be done as the build process is old and certain parts may not be necessary. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read the product documentation on http://visualstudio.com

Comment: Which one  you want to achieve?   Migrate old XAML build definition to new Vnext build definition from TFS to VSTS, or just migrate new build Vnext definition from TFS to VSTS？ What's the detail version of your TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Migrate New Vnext build definition from TFS to VSTS**

If you want to template your builds or move them from TFS to VSTS, you could also use the REST API's to perform this.  Details please refer this blog: [HOW TO MOVE BUILD DEFINITIONS IN TFS TO OTHER PROJECTS USING THE REST API](https://writeabout.net/2016/03/03/how-to-move-build-definitions-in-tfs-to-other-projects-using-the-rest-api/)

Another example shown [here](http://www.ericksegaar.com/2015/10/16/using-json-via-rest-to-create-build-definitions-in-vso/). It shows how to get the JSON response of a build definition and again using the same reference to make a new one in the project you desire.

---

**Migrate Old XAML to New Vnext build definition from TFS to VSTS**

Unfortunately, there will not be **any automated conversion processes**. The new builds are based on a different architecture and run on a completely different system. And you can use both the new builds and agents alongside your XAML builds, controllers, and agents.

> If you have heavily customized XAML builds and custom activities, you
>   can continue using those builds until you are ready to port your
>   business logic into scripts that can run in the new builds.

You should also take a look at [these series of articles](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2016/01/upgrading-from-xaml-to-build-2015-with.html) by *jessehouwing* devoted specifically to the case like yours.

---

About *how to  create a build*, you could refer this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/dot-net) from MSDN.

Comment: trying to add this to tfs I get "This extension targets Visual Studio 2017 but was not built with an up-to-date VSSDK. Please make sure to update your references and try uploading again. Note: you'll also need to add Prerequisites to your extension.vsixmanifest." - I presumed this tool was for VSTS to VSTS build migration

Comment: You can also try to use the REST API's to perform this. Which template your builds, and then make a new one in the project you desire. Please see my update answer.